# Bundle javascript library with namespace and classes in different files

Tags: javascript, typescript, bundle, javascript-namespaces

I have different files with namespace and classes like this:

**1) namespace.js:**

```
var somenamespace = window.somenamespace || {};
```

**2) class1.js:**

```
somenamespace.class1= (function() {
  var _public = {};
  _public.someBoolean= false;
  return _public;
})();
```

**3) class2.js:**

```
somenamespace.class2= (function() {
  var _public = {};
  _public.init= function() {
  };
  return _public;
})();
```

I need to bundle them and expose them on a library. Something like this:

```
expose default {
  somenamespace
};
```

in order to use it in another project. Something like this:

```
import * as somenamespace from 'somenamespace';

var a = function() {
    somenamespace.class1.someBoolean = true;
    ansomenamespace.class2.init();
};
```

How can I do it? (I would like also expose its types definition for typescript use) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the `import` / `export` style modules and the type that are attached to `window`.  I would recommend picking one or the other.

---

For example to attach everything to `window`:

**namespace.js**

```js
var somenamespace = window.somenamespace || {}; // not strictly necessary
```

**class1.js**

```
var somenamespace = window.somenamespace || {};

somenamespace.class1= (function() {
  var _public = {};
  _public.someBoolean= false;
  return _public;
})();
```

**class2.js**

```
var somenamespace = window.somenamespace || {};

somenamespace.class2= (function() {
  var _public = {};
  _public.init= function() {
  };
  return _public;
})();
```

**using the module**

```
// no import, just read it off of window

var a = function() {
    window.somenamespace.class1.someBoolean = true;
    window.ansomenamespace.class2.init();
};
```

---

Alternatively, I'd recommend `import` / `export`, though you need to be transpiling your code with Babel or Webpack or something similar, since not all browsers support ES modules:

**namespace.js**

```
export {class1} from './class1'
export {class2} from './class2'
```

**class1.js**

```
export const class1 = (function() {
  var _public = {};
  _public.someBoolean= false;
  return _public;
})();
```

**class2.js**

```
export const class2 = (function() {
  var _public = {};
  _public.init= function() {
  };
  return _public;
})();
```

**using the module**

```
import * as somenamespace from './namespace'

var a = function() {
    somenamespace.class1.someBoolean = true;
    ansomenamespace.class2.init();
};
```